# Do not output small decimal numbers in scientific / exponential notation

Tags: csvhelper

Some numbers in my dataset are very small, e.g. `0.00008`.
When I write out to CSV, the value in the text itself is `8E-05`.

I need the value to be written out to CSV in decimal notation.
Can this be achieved without having to specify the format of every single field in the CsvMap?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out one can specify a format per-type on the writer Configuration property.

e.g.

```
using (var writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(exportCsv, append)))
{
    writer.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = !append;
    writer.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<GeoVulcanCollarCsvMap>();
    writer.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<double?>().Formats = new[] { "0.######################" };
    writer.WriteRecords(list);
}
```